# How long does it take to upgrade the T&T Mart

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

I have the T&T Mart and finally it is going to construct into Super T&T Mart. I really want to know when my shop will open.

Answer (score 1):

It will close for only one day (the day mentioned on the announcement sign), reopening the next day.

Answer (score 0):

When you see the upgrading notification on your Town Announcements Board, it will construct the next day. The day after that, the store will open.